# блок съезжает влево

Tags: вёрстка

блок с﻿ъезжает влево ﻿хотя я главному блоку и тем которые внутри  дал margin: 0 auto;﻿

помогите понять причи﻿ну бага или наити его

сайт  http://frontend-er.h1n.ru/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Дайте блоку с классом  `header__main` стили - `margin: 0 auto`﻿ и будет он у вас по центру

Comment: я же написал что главному блоку я задал margin 0 auto

Comment: его надо задавать ВСЕМ которые хотите выровнять